# Comparing each letter with the next

Tags: python

I am trying to compare each letter of the list with the next and if the subtraction is less than 1, I would like the number being compared to be printed.

```
lis=[2,3,5,6,7,8,0,4,2,5,6,8,9,4,2,]
for number in lis:
    if lis[number+1]-lis[number]==1:
        print (number)
```

The output is

```
2
3
0
4
2
9
4
2
```

The code completely skips 5,6,7
But prints numbers that don't really fit the statement.
Can anyone please explain?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you post the code?

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the *indices* of the list with the *values*.

For example, the first element of your list has index 0 but value 2. The next has index 1 but value 3. The next has index 2 but value 5. When you use `lis[index]`, the result is a value.

When you use `for number in lis`, that iterates over the values, not the indices.

Here's one way to do what I think you're going for:

```
lis=[2,3,5,6,7,8,0,4,2,5,6,8,9,4,2,]
for index, value in enumerate(lis[:-1]): #don't go all the way to the end because you're comparing with the next
    if lis[index+1]-value <= 1: #you wanted less than, right?
        print (value)
```

Comment: For your reference, this is an [anti-pattern](https://docs.quantifiedcode.com/python-anti-patterns/readability/not_using_zip_to_iterate_over_a_pair_of_lists.html#anti-pattern) to not use zip to iterate over two lists.

Comment: I agree that your solution is more elegant - since OP seems to have some confusion on list basics, I thought it would be clearest to stay simple. (I'm also not convinced that this is really a case of iterating over two lists.)

Comment: Sure, just saying! ;)

Comment: For some reason, Python still gives me an error message at the end of the print saying "list index out of range". I guess the program reaches the last number of the list and doesn't have any number to compare to? Thanks for your help, I am just starting learning it, sorry if I am kinda slow

Comment: Hmm. Are you definitely including the [:-1]? Can you post the exact code you're using?

Comment: I just realized I messed up. I typed [::-1], which reversed the whole thing. It's working fine now! Thanks so much!

Comment: Hah, glad to hear it. You can accept the answer you found most helpful using the green check mark.

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate through the list by pair of consecutive elements by using slicing and `zip`:

```
lis = [2,3,5,6,7,8,0,4,2,5,6,8,9,4,2,]

for n, m in zip(lis, lis[1:]):
    if m - n == 1:
        print(n)
```